# Updating a client regularly(scheduled) and on demand via signalR

Tags: .net, signalr

I am building something that is using SignalR to push data to the client, this is working properly. What I am debating on is how to handle doing the push.

Data can be pushed via regular schedule (ie 5pm every day), or if a user goes to the site and clicks push now, it will send the data immediately.

Should I create a background application that is in an infinate loop deciding if a push needs to be sent (sounds like a waste of cpu and a challenge considering I have a shared host, not an owned server)? For the most part, everything can be database driven if there is a way to hook into a data on change event. At the same time, I don't fully trust sql triggers and being shared atm, I can't turn on clr. This will be for a fairly large number of connected machines eventually(easily 250k+ concurrently), so efficiency is a concern.

Note: the core of the site is built in mvc .net.

Comment: 250000 clients at the same time? wow :)

Comment: Think of it more like an alarm system. A lot of connections, but not much data transfer.

Comment: if its on a schedule then you don't have a choice, if its by user request then you also don't have a choice, if its both then do both.

Comment: thepirat000 is right -> you should not underestimate the complexity involved and resources needed to support 250K. We support in signalR ~10K connections / server. But this isn't easy.

So, you're talking about 25 servers at least, load-balanced of course and scaled-out, to ensure you multiplex/broadcast as you expect.

Comment: @penderi I've used socket connections in the past, but not on this scale. I was understanding the only resource really used to keep the connection alive is memory (at least when no data is being transferred). So I was expecting a single server to handle a good amount more than 10k connections with enough memory. Am I mistaken? Per day, I would expect under a gig of data transfer for all the 250k connections.

Comment: Hi VirtualLife. I entered into the signalR world under such misconecptions. Whilst you're right *maintaining* 10K connections is ok, the ramp up of connections (i.e. opening) is CPU intensive. That's the issue - the ramp up of load. 

A quick way of proving this is to see how quickly you can get 10K connection on a box. Anything more agressive that a few mins (using crank) would hit a CPU spike - or at least it's what we found!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a CronJob to do this. You could use [this one](https://www.setcronjob.com/), the [Azure WebJobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) or another one.

EDIT:
Let me help you a little bit more, I've working in this scenario many times before, and it is something that is common in many applications.

First, you should create a method controller that, when triggered, the desired effect should happen in the applications. An example of this would be a controller method that every time it is called, updated some entries in a database.

After you've wrote the controller, TEST IT. Make sure everything work as expected. This is a very critical point if you are WRITING data to the database, as the action is going to happen automatically.

Then, read about Cronjobs, or webjobs. They are basically a call to a URL, which can be set in a timely manner. For example, you could create a cronjob that goes to http://yoursite.com every minute, o every week.

Finally, create a Cronjob that calls your controller method. (You won't be able to test a cronjob if your application is not published though, test the method locally by typing the controller url in the browser's bar)

Comment: Made some changes to your original post, digging a little bit deeper about what VirtualLife has to do, and about Cronjobs.